# Animate multiple div independently using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to perform a cloud moving animation using jquery.

This is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yYpT/)

I want the three clouds to start at a different staring point and move at different speeds. after the animation is complete once, I want the clouds to start from the right extreme of the screen and continue on with their speed.

In my example, the first pass starts right, but after that everything seems to align together which i dont want. As soon as one clouds finishes its completion I want it to start from the right again, not waiting for the other two.

This is the function that I call on load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function loopc1() {
        $('#cloud').css({ right: 0 });
        $('#cloud').animate({
            right: '900',
        }, 15000, 'linear', function () {
            loopc1();
        });
    }

    function loopc2() {
        $('#cloud1').animate({
            right: '900',
        }, 15000, 'linear', function () {
            $('#cloud1').css({ right: 0 });
            loopc2();
        });
    }

    function loopc3() {
        $('#cloud2').animate({
            right: '900',
        }, 15000, 'linear', function () {
            $('#cloud2').css({ right: 0 });
            loopc3();
        });
    }



    loopc1();
    loopc2();
    loopc3();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set 15000ms for all three clouds, try setting different time for different cloud for animating. such as :

```
    function loopc1() {
    $('#cloud').css({ right: 0 });
    $('#cloud').animate({
        right: '900',
    }, 15000, 'linear', function () {
        loopc1();
    });
}

function loopc2() {
    $('#cloud1').animate({
        right: '900',
    }, 20000, 'linear', function () {
        $('#cloud1').css({ right: 0 });
        loopc2();
    });
}

function loopc3() {
    $('#cloud2').animate({
        right: '900',
    }, 25000, 'linear', function () {
        $('#cloud2').css({ right: 0 });
        loopc3();
    });
}
```